# How to load any one of many .txt file randomly

Tags: java, android, android-resources

I am fairly new in java and have to make android app for my project. so, how do i  load randomly any one of many .txt file  that i had provided as option in raw folder. This should be a piece of cake for you guys out there !

```
InputStream questions = this.getBaseContext().getResources()
.openRawResource(R.raw.questions);
bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(questions));
```

Using above method, i m able to load only one file: **questions.txt** from folder **res>raw**.
 But, i want to randomly load any one of these five txt file **(*res/raw/questionset1,questionset2,questionset3,questionset4,questionset5***) to get variation in questions asked
            **Full code on how i load single file could be seen below**

```
private void loadQuestions() throws Exception {
        try {

    InputStream questions = this.getBaseContext().getResources()
            .openRawResource(R.raw.questions); 
        bReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(questions));
    StringBuilder quesString = new StringBuilder();
    String aJsonLine = null;
    while ((aJsonLine = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
        quesString.append(aJsonLine);
    }
    Log.d(this.getClass().toString(), quesString.toString());
    JSONObject quesObj = new JSONObject(quesString.toString());
    quesList = quesObj.getJSONArray("Questions");
    Log.d(this.getClass().getName(),
            "Num Questions " + quesList.length());
    } catch (Exception e){

    } finally {
        try {
            bReader.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("", e.getMessage().toString(), e.getCause());
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Do you know the names of text files before hand? If not, read them first. Put them in a collection, let's call it names. Get a random number from 0 to names.size() - 1. Pick the name from names collection. If you need to read a text file for only once, drop that name from names. If not, save read indexes separately so that you can check each random number, if it has been used before. And keep going.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use raw resources for this purpose. Put your files in the `Assets` folder subfolder, e.g. `questions`. Later, do something like this:

```
String [] list = getAssets().list("questions");
```

I think this is the path format here, but I am hand-typing, mind that. It may be "/questions" or something like that. Also, getAssets() must be called on or from a `Context` object, so do it i your `Activity`.

This will return the list of files in the subdirectory. Now use a Random() object to select a number between 0 and `list.length` and you have your random file :-) Open it with `getAssets().open(path + /* your randomed String file name */)`